# Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this form where user registers his/her details and saves it in google firestore, which actually works because the details are stored in firestore and i can log in with those details if i want but i keep getting this error whenever i submit the details.

```
I/zygote  (20683): Do partial code cache collection, code=56KB, data=61KB
I/zygote  (20683): After code cache collection, code=55KB, data=60KB
I/zygote  (20683): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/GraphicBuffer(20683): register, handle(0x8d0f9bc0) (w:720 h:1344 s:720 f:0x1 u:f02)
I/zygote  (20683): Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=109KB
I/zygote  (20683): After code cache collection, code=99KB, data=69KB
W/System  (20683): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(20683): isEmailSend:POST
I/System.out(20683): port:443
I/System.out(20683): Check isMmsSendPdu
I/System.out(20683): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
W/System  (20683): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(20683): isEmailSend:POST
I/System.out(20683): Check isMmsSendPdu
I/System.out(20683): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/FirebaseAuth(20683): Notifying id token listeners about user ( BFN7FUKuGvMpIBaYSIpxnbkTjzB3 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(20683): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( BFN7FUKuGvMpIBaYSIpxnbkTjzB3 ).
W/DynamiteModule(20683): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(20683): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(20683): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/zygote  (20683): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/zygote  (20683): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/SharedPreferencesImpl(20683): Time required to fsync /data/user/0/com.brightapps.book_club/shared_prefs/com.google.firebase.auth.api.Store.W0RFRkFVTFRd+MToyMTI3NDMzNDk2MjE6YW5kcm9pZDplMjc0M2UyNTMwMDNlZGM2YTVkZjNj.xml: [<1: 0, <2: 0, <4: 0, <8: 0, <16: 0, <32: 0, <64: 0, <128: 0, <256: 0, <512: 0, <1024: 0, <2048: 0, <4096: 1, <8192: 0, <16384: 0, >=16384: 0]
V/NativeCrypto(20683): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 288 native methods...
I/ProviderInstaller(20683): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/System.out(20683): port:443
I/zygote  (20683): Do partial code cache collection, code=125KB, data=97KB
I/zygote  (20683): After code cache collection, code=125KB, data=97KB
I/zygote  (20683): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

I have used both emulator and my mobile device (which is what am using for this error above) to test it and its still the same

**flutter doctor -v**

```
P:\flutter\book_club>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.1 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (2 months ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
    • Dart version 2.10.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\brightisaac\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\brightisaac\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Infinix X606C (mobile)             • ************* • android-arm • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554    • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Please how can i fix this. if you need more material to help you understand please ask

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @John Nope i just left it as it is since it hasn't cause any problem and everything is still ok

Answer (score 0):

If the app is still able to access cloud_firestore without issues, it's likely the messages in the logs are just warnings that can be safely ignored. Usually, issues where plugins aren't referenced correct are solved by running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. Here's a [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4447) discussing an issue with a similar error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually ignore this warning. This should not affect the behavior of your application.

But there are some workaround that can eliminate the warning:

- Make sure that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` is defined in all the three *AndroidManifest.xml* files, i.e `debug/main/profile`. For some, having `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in main AndroidManifest file also helps.
- Sometimes outdated google play services can also cause these warnings so update google play services this happens mostly in the case of an emulator.
- If you are running your app on older device make user that [multidex](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Android-Multidex-support) is enabled.